# Height / Width of an iframe

Tags: html, css, web

So when I try to change the height and width of that item, the curve inside it ( which I want to change ) doesn't actually change but the border around it does.
I'd like to have some help with it and thanks ^^

[image: How it looks (the red border is the one that changes)]

```html
<iframe style ="height: 450px; width:900px; position: relative; align-self: center; align-content: center;" src="https://thingspeak.com/channels/1270796/charts/1bgcolor=%23ffffff&color=%23d62020&dynamic=true&results=60&type=line&update=15"></iframe>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome! First of all, no inline style. Include the style into the <style></style> tag in your header.

Comment: Will it change something? or just a way of getting your code organized? 
*new to html and css by the way*

Comment: Definitely the second, maybe the first too ;) I was checking here on SO there are several similar questions, about adjusting iframe content to iframe dimension

Comment: Target the image, not the frame, if you want to resize it